# Pass Textbox Value From Windows Form To Class

Tags: c#, winforms

I am learning C# and have run into an interesting issue to me.  I have a class variable defined as public and I instantiate a new instance of my form in my class and access the value of the public variable it is always null.

To further explain my issue - this syntax prints the appropriate value

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tboxvalue.ToString());
```

However, this syntax is always outputting a 0

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(f1.tboxvalue.ToString());
```

How do I need to alter my syntax so that the correct value is passed to the class `Functions`?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public double tboxvalue;
    private string exportdata;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClicker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Functions.EE();
    }
    private void txtData_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool @checked = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;

        if (@checked.ToString() == "True")
        {
            exportdata = "Yes";
            tboxvalue = Convert.ToDouble(this.txtData.Text);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tboxvalue.ToString());
        }
        else
            exportdata = "No";
    }
}
class Functions
{
    public static void EE()
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(f1.tboxvalue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `new Form1()` creates a new form (!!)  It wont be the same form you might see elsewhere on the screen

Comment: @NewContributor - how do I access the variable from the class w/o instantiating a new instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access properties of the form, you need to change two Things. First you have to pass the `form` to the `'EE'` method, then you can access the form's properties. Second, don't create a new form in 'EE' method.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public double tboxvalue;
    private string exportdata;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClicker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Functions.EE(this);
    }
    private void txtData_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool @checked = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;

        if (@checked.ToString() == "True")
        {
            exportdata = "Yes";
            tboxvalue = Convert.ToDouble(this.txtData.Text);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tboxvalue.ToString());
        }
        else
            exportdata = "No";
    }
}
class Functions
{
    public static void EE(Form1 f1)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(f1.tboxvalue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question i guess you are recreated Form1 with own textbox or labels when you click btnClicker button. You can reassign your form objects where you created it.

Answer (score 0):

You might add static Form1 object and Setter routine to Functions class:

```
    private static Form1 _form;

    public static void SetForm(Form1 form)
    {
        _form = form;
    }
```

and pass the form to the class in Form_Load event-click on the form twice:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Functions.SetForm(this);
    }
```

Then you can play with the form in Functions class using the object _form

good luck!